# Does reversing the polynomial preserve the number of the roots in the right-hand-side of the complex plane? If so, why?

Tags: polynomials, stability-theory

The Routh-Hurwitz Stability Criterion is essentially an algorithm to determine how many roots a polynomial has in the right-hand-side of the complex plane (that is, how many of its roots have positive real part) without having to actually calculate those roots (which is, in principle, impossible for high-degree polynomials). However, sometimes this algorithm runs into the division by zero error, and you have to calculate it using limits. However, [this video by Neso Academy](https://youtu.be/eP4Ymo785OI) claims that there is an easier way: simply replace `s` in the polynomial with `1/z`. Does that really always work? If so, how?

Replacing `s` in the polynomial with `1/z`, as far as I understand it, effectively "reverses" it (that's how I implemented it in [my implementation of the Routh-Hurwitz Stability Criterion](https://flatassembler.github.io/hurwitz.html)). For example, the polynomial `a*s^2 + b*s + c` becomes `c*z^2 + b*z + a`. And the polynomial `a*s^3 + b*s^2 + c*s + d` becomes `d*s^3 + c*s^2 + b*s + a`. So, does "reversing" the polynomial preserve the number of the roots in the right-hand-side of the complex plane (that is, the number of roots with a positive real part)? If so, why?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Alt. hint: $\,\dfrac{1}{z} = \dfrac{\bar z}{|z|^2}\,$, and $\,z, \bar z$ lie in the same right/left-hand-side half-plane.

Comment: @dxiv Well, I don't know much about complicated numbers, to be honest.

Comment: @FlatAssembler My comment only assumed you knew that $z \bar z = |z|^2$ and $\operatorname{Re}{z}=\operatorname{Re}{\bar z}$, which I thought were fair assumptions since the question was about complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, reversing the polynomial $p(x)$ with complex roots $\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n\}$ gives a polynomial $q(x)$ with complex roots $\left\{\frac{1}{r_1},\frac{1}{r_2},\dots,\frac{1}{r_n}\right\}$.

Furthermore, for some nonzero root $r=a+bi$ of $p(x)$, the real part of $\frac{1}{r}$ must have the same sign as the real part of $r$, as

$$
\frac{1}{r}=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i
$$

and $a^2+b^2>0$.

So $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ must have the same number of roots with positive (or negative, or zero) real part.